# Decrypting AES and HMAC with PyCrypto

Tags: python, encryption, hmac, pycrypto, cryptojs

Having a bit of trouble getting a AES cipher text to decrypt.

In this particular scenario, I am encrypting data on the client side with Crypto-JS and decrypting it back on a python server with PyCrypto.

encrypt.js:

```
  var password = 'BJhtfRjKnTDTtPXUBnErKDxfkiMCOLyP';
  var data = 'mytext';

  var masterKey = CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString();

  // Derive keys for AES and HMAC
  var length = masterKey.toString().length / 2
  var encryptionKey = masterKey.substr(0, length);
  var hmacKey = masterKey.substr(length);

  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(64/8);

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    data,
    encryptionKey,
    {
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB
    }
  );

  var concat = iv + encrypted;

  // Calculate HMAC using iv and cipher text
  var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(concat, hmacKey);

  // Put it all together
  var registrationKey = iv + encrypted + hash;

  // Encode in Base64
  var basemessage = btoa(registrationKey);
```

decrypt.py:

```
class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        key_hash = SHA256.new(key).hexdigest()
        # Derive keys
        encryption_key = key_hash[:len(key_hash)/2]
        self.key = encryption_key            
        self.hmac_key = key_hash[len(key_hash)/2:]


    def verify_hmac(self, input_cipher, hmac_key):
        # Calculate hash using inputted key
        new_hash = HMAC.new(hmac_key, digestmod=SHA256)
        new_hash.update(input_cipher)
        digest = new_hash.hexdigest()

        # Calculate hash using derived key from local password
        local_hash = HMAC.new(self.hmac_key, digestmod=SHA256)
        local_hash.update(input_cipher)
        local_digest = local_hash.hexdigest()

        return True if digest == local_digest else False


    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        hmac = enc[60:]
        cipher_text = enc[16:60]

        # Verify HMAC using concatenation of iv + cipher like in js
        verified_hmac = self.verify_hmac((iv+cipher_text), self.hmac_key)

        if verified_hmac:
            cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
            return cipher.decrypt(cipher_text)


password = 'BJhtfRjKnTDTtPXUBnErKDxfkiMCOLyP'

input = 'long base64 registrationKey...'

cipher = AESCipher(password)
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(input)
```

I'm successful in re-calculating the HMAC but when I try and then decrypt the cipher I get something that seems encrypted with �'s in the result.

I was getting errors about input length of cipher text but when I switched to CFB mode that fixed it so I don't think it's a padding issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

## Client (JavaScript):

- AES has a block size of 128 bit and CFB mode expects a full block for the IV. Use

  ```
  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
  ```
- The `iv` and `hash` variables are WordArray objects, but `encrypted` is not. When you force them to be converted to strings by concatenating them (`+`), `iv` and `hash` are Hex-encoded, but `encrypted` is formatted in an OpenSSL compatible format and Base64-encoded. You need to access the `ciphertext` property to get the encrypted WordArray:

  ```
  var concat = iv + encrypted.ciphertext;
  ```

  and

  ```
  var registrationKey = iv + encrypted.ciphertext + hash;
  ```
- `registrationKey` is hex-encoded. There is no need to encode it again with Base64 and bloat it even more:

  ```
  var basemessage = registrationKey;
  ```

  If you want to convert the hex encoded `registrationKey` to base64 encoding, use:

  ```
  var basemessage = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(registrationKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  ```
- `concat` is a hex-encoded string of the IV and ciphertext, because you forced the stringification by "adding" (`+`) `iv` and `encrypted`. The `HmacSHA256()` function takes either a WordArray object or a string. When you pass a string in, as you do, it will assume that the data is UTF-8 encoded and try to decode it as UTF-8. You need to parse the data yourself into a WordArray:

  ```
  var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(concat), hmacKey);
  ```
- The `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` and `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256()` expect the key either as a WordArray object or as a string. As before, if the key is supplied as a string, a UTF-8 encoding is assumed which is not the case here. You better parse the strings into WordArrays yourself:

  ```
  var encryptionKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(masterKey.substr(0, length));
  var hmacKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(masterKey.substr(length));
  ```

## Server (Python):

- You're not verifying anything in `verify_hmac()`. You hash the same data with the same key twice. What you need to do is hash the IV+ciphertext and compare the result with the hash (called tag or HMAC-tag) that you slice off the full ciphertext.

  ```
  def verify_hmac(self, input_cipher, mac):
      # Calculate hash using derived key from local password
      local_hash = HMAC.new(self.hmac_key, digestmod=SHA256)
      local_hash.update(input_cipher)
      local_digest = local_hash.digest()

      return mac == local_digest
  ```

  And later in `decrypt()`:

  ```
  verified_hmac = self.verify_hmac((iv+cipher_text), hmac)
  ```
- You need to correctly slice off the MAC. The 60 that is hardcoded is a bad idea. Since you're using SHA-256 the MAC is 32 bytes long, so you do this

  ```
  hmac = enc[-32:]
  cipher_text = enc[16:-32]
  ```
- The CFB mode is actually a set of similar modes. The actual mode is determined by the segment size. CryptoJS only supports segments of 128 bit. So you need tell pycrypto to use the same mode as in CryptoJS:

  ```
  cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
  ```

  If you want to use CFB mode with a segment size of 8 bit (default of pycrypto), you can use a modified version of CFB in CryptoJS from my project: [Extension for CryptoJS](https://github.com/artjomb/cryptojs-extension#cfb)

Full client code:

```js
var password = 'BJhtfRjKnTDTtPXUBnErKDxfkiMCOLyP';
var data = 'mytext';

var masterKey = CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString();
var length = masterKey.length / 2
var encryptionKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(masterKey.substr(0, length));
var hmacKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(masterKey.substr(length));

var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    data,
    encryptionKey,
    {
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB
    }
);

var concat = iv + encrypted.ciphertext; 
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(concat), hmacKey);
var registrationKey = iv + encrypted.ciphertext + hash;
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(registrationKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
```

Full server code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import HMAC, SHA256
import base64
import binascii

class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        key_hash = SHA256.new(key).hexdigest()
        self.hmac_key = binascii.unhexlify(key_hash[len(key_hash)/2:])
        self.key = binascii.unhexlify(key_hash[:len(key_hash)/2])

    def verify_hmac(self, input_cipher, mac):
        local_hash = HMAC.new(self.hmac_key, digestmod=SHA256)
        local_hash.update(input_cipher)
        local_digest = local_hash.digest()

        return SHA256.new(mac).digest() == SHA256.new(local_digest).digest() # more or less constant-time comparison

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        hmac = enc[-32:]
        cipher_text = enc[16:-32]

        verified_hmac = self.verify_hmac((iv+cipher_text), hmac)

        if verified_hmac:
            cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
            return cipher.decrypt(cipher_text)
        else:
            return 'Bad Verify'


password = 'BJhtfRjKnTDTtPXUBnErKDxfkiMCOLyP'

input = "btu0CCFbvdYV4B/j7hezAra6Q6u6KB8n5QcyA32JFLU8QRd+jLGW0GxMQsTqxaNaNkcU2I9r1ls4QUPUpaLPQg=="

obj = AESCipher(password)
decryption = obj.decrypt(input)

print 'Decrypted message:', decryption
```

Comment: First off, thank you so much for taking the time to write up the great answer! I'm still learning about cryptography and this was a breath of fresh air.

After implementing the code, some errors came up though. First off, the hash verification kept coming back as None. After just setting the result to True to try the next part, I still got foreign encoded text.

Also, I was confused by the IV. You doubled the length in js but in python, you still only grab the first half of it ([:16]). An error is thrown  if you try and get more but it doesn't make much sense to only get half. Thanks again!

Comment: (1) I missed two encoding problems in the client code and added them to my answer. (2) It shouldn't be possible for the HMAC verification to return `None`. I don't know what's going on there. (3) The `128/8` part in CryptoJS creates a 16 byte IV. When you encode it to hex, it will be 32 *characters* long. If you use the Hex to Base64 conversion code, then your python code should correctly decode the Base64-encoded ciphertext and the IV should be 16 bytes long.

Comment: Thanks again for the response! Still no dice for some reason. I was wondering about the `concat` in the js and how it doesn't have `encrypted.ciphertext` like `registrationKey` does. Does it not need it? Also the `None` result was on me. I also decided to forego the base64 encoding since you said it was just bloat. Thanks so much again for your great help. I feel like it's really close. I consolidated the current code into pastebin's to make this a bit more organized. Javascript: http://pastebin.com/R4Ni0MpC, Python: http://pastebin.com/N6vcVq45

Comment: There were more encoding problems. I've added the full working code

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! You went above and beyond for me and I only wish I could give you bonus points. I was playing around with the unhexlify but wasn't applying it to the keys. Thanks again. You win the day.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out the decryption for the javascript lol

Comment: Yes, that's a little more challenging, because a WordArray doesn't support slice. The workaround is either to work on hex strings and convert their slices into IV, ciphertext and MAC; or slice the `words` property on the ciphertext: `iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(ciphertext.words.slice(0, 4))`.

Comment: fantastic answer, but I am a bit worried about the verification of the hmac being with ==. Might be vulnerable to timing attack. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html#hmac.compare_digest

Comment: @Chris You're completely right. As this is meant to be compatible with a most versions of Python and PyCrypto, it is a more manual process of ensuring constant-time comparison. Note that the newest version of PyCrypto also implements a constant-time verify function which is not yet documented. There is an old-school fix for that...

Comment: @ArtjomB. I see the hmac comparison in the PyCrypto sourcecode (https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py) but I don't actually see it on import which is odd though. See here: https://gist.github.com/chrisdl/eeed99d7a9edc4f1b2e0df60d00d6fca I ended up using the built in hmac verify which was added in python 2.7.7

Comment: @Chris It was added in 2.7a1 which is not a stable release.